# make row clickable after refresh in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a row clickable after a refresh. I have this in the view:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr class="@(item.Id == (int)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? ".tr.sfs-selected  .table.sfs-selectable tbody .dataTable sfs-selected .dataTable sfs-selectable .table-responsive" : String.Empty)" onclick="'<tr>'" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", item.Id } })">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled)
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have this jQuery:

```
$("table.sfs-selectable tbody").on("click", "tr", function (ev) {
    var $row = $("tr.sfs-selected").each(function(){
        selectRow($row, !$row.hasClass("sfs-selected"));
    });
});
```

However the row is not clicked after refresh.

Thank you

the view:

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable sfs-selectable sfs-col1-right-aligned">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.Id).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "id", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "id" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("id", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.Name).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "name", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "name" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("name", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.IsEnabled).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "enabled", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "enabled" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("enabled", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.FormName).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "formname", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "formname" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("formname", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.TemplateName).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "design", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "design" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("design", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Resources.Entity.Product.PublicUrl, "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "urlname", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "urlname" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("urlname", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.SubmittedForms)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.RouteLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => firstItem.ModificationDate).ToString(), "Sort-Product", new { sortColumn = "modified", sortOrder = (ViewBag.sortColumn == "modified" && ViewBag.sortOrder != "desc") ? "desc" : "", searchString = ViewBag.SearchString })
                                @ViewHelper.GetSortIndicator("modified", ViewBag.sortColumn, ViewBag.sortOrder)
                            </th>
                            <th class="hidden"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model) {

                                                    <tr class="@(item.Id == (int)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? ".tr.sfs-selected  .table.sfs-selectable tbody .dataTable sfs-selected .dataTable sfs-selectable .table-responsive" : String.Empty)"   data-url="@Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", item.Id } })">
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled)
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @{
                            bool viewLink = item.IsEnabled;
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FormName)) {
                                var form = item.FormLibraryEntry;
                                if (form == null) {
                                    viewLink = false;
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormName)
                                                                <em>(@Resources.Entity.Environment.Removed)</em>
                                }
                                else {
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => form.Name)
                                                                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "FormLibrary", new { id = item.FormName })"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link-square text-info"></i></a>
                                }
                            }
                                                            }
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @{
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.TemplateName)) {
                                var template = item.TemplateLibraryEntry;
                                if (template == null) {
                                    viewLink = false;
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TemplateName)
                                                                <em>(@Resources.Entity.Environment.Removed)</em>
                                }
                                else {
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => template.Name)
                                                                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "DesignTemplate", new { id = item.TemplateName })"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link-square text-info"></i></a>
                                }
                            }
                                                            }
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlName)) {
                                        var defaultProductUri = CustomerConfig.ToHostUri(Request.Url.Scheme, defaultHostHeader, Request.Url.Port, (isProduction ? "" : "TEST/") + item.UrlName);
                                        if (viewLink) {
                                            @item.UrlName
                                                                <a href="@defaultProductUri.ToString()" title="@Resources.Entity.Product.ViewProduct" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link-square text-info"></i></a>
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            @item.UrlName
                                        }
                                    }
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @{

                            int cnt = item.SubmittedForms.Where(prod => prod.Order.IsProduction == isProduction).Count();
                            @(cnt.ToString() + " ")
                            if (cnt > 0) {
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SubmittedForms", new { filter = item.Id })">
                                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link-square text-info"></i>
                                </a>

                            }
                                                            }
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-nowrap">
                                                            @item.ModificationDate.ToString("G")
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="hidden">
                                                            <span>


                                                                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FormName)) {
                                                                    @Html.RouteLink(Resources.Action.Navigation.Preview, "ProductPreview", new { productUrl = item.UrlName, customerSchema = custSchema }, new { target = "_blank" })
                                        }
                                        else { @(Resources.Action.Navigation.Preview)  }
                                                                | @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Action.Navigation.Details, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
                                                                | @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Action.Navigation.Edit, "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>



                                                    </tr>



                        }





                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

so I have tbody in it. but the problem is now that I have to double click on a row

this is the selectRow function:

```
function selectRow($row, doSel) {
            var $section = $row.closest("section");
            if (doSel) {
                $section.find("tr.sfs-selected").removeClass("sfs-selected");
                $row.addClass("sfs-selected");
                $section.find(".sfs-actionbutton").each(function (index) {
                    var $btn = $(this);
                    $btn.addClass("disabled");
                    var href = $row.find("td:last a").filter(function () {
                        return $(this).text().trim() == $btn.text().trim();
                    }).attr("href");

                    if (href) {
                        $btn.attr("href", href).removeClass("disabled");
                        if ($btn.parent().is(".btn-group")) {
                            $btn.parent().children("a").removeClass("disabled");
                            $btn.attr("data-href", href + "/");
                            $btn.attr("href", href + "/" + $(".sfs-select-preview-template .active a").attr("href"));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $row.removeClass("sfs-selected");
                $section.find(".sfs-actionbutton").addClass("disabled");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'refresh'? A full reload of the page?

Comment: yes a full reload. But I also see this error in script: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'hasClass' of undefined or null reference

Comment: What do you want a click on a table row to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have wrong selector, i gess it should be like this:

```
var $row = $("tr.sfs-selected").each(function(){
        selectRow( $(this), $(this).hasClass("sfs-selected"));
    });
```

The point is in `each()` method you can get one of collection element with `this` keyword.

Comment: Thank you. But The problem is if I do that the first time I have to double click on row for selection

Comment: @hallohallo but what `selectRow` function do?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be specifying class names by adding leading dots `.` to them, but I don't think you mean to have them like that (or the jQuery selectors won't work). Also the inline `onclick` is not in a working state, but your jQuery event should take care of that so that can be removed.

```
<tr class="@(item.Id == (int)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", item.Id } })">
```

Now, I am assuming you don't really want a classes named `tbody dataTable table-responsive` on each row either, so I removed them. They should probably be set on the `<table>` and/or `<tbody>` but if you need them back just re-add them.

For you jQuery:

The call to `selectRow()` seems a bit odd, since it will only iterate table rows with class `sfs-selected`, hence it will always call the function with `selectRow($(element), false)`.

**In other words**: when you click a table row any row with class `sfs-selected` will have it's class removed and *actionbutton* will be disabled. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: @hallohallo You had both an non-working inline `onclick`, and a jQuery `click` event bound to the `<tr>`'s. It's probably the reason a double click was needed. My example `<tr>` above has no such inline event.